# Auto Login to .Net Mvc website via email link

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web application which send an email to each user with a link to redirect to the web site.

This link should be redirected to a page containing specific information for each email. So I will have to send a query string with the link(a specific id for each email. this id can be used to identify the user as well)
User should be logged in to view the page data.

How can I create a auto login for this scenario?
Additionally How can I secure the query string parameter?

Comment: This is not a question. This is business requirement. You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random token for each email you send and save against the respective Id.

Include this token in your query string as 1 of the parameter

Encode the query string using base64 encoding.

When you receive a request decode the query string parameters and validate it against the token saved against the Id with the one you receive from URL.

I hope this helps.